# What grease / lubricant to use on aluminum threads?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aluminum, threads

I have a coffee grinder with fine aluminum threading as adjustment mechanism. (The rotation is also done while under springs load).
The threading is of a 10cm diameter.

I had to clean the threads completely from its original lube/grease and tried using either petroleum or Molykote 111 to re-lubricate and it seems they are not good.
The petroleum is too thin, slips too easily and under load you can still feel the seizing.
The Molykote 111 is too sticky and the mechanism is very very difficult to rotate.

Just to clarify, although this is a coffee grinder, there is no usual contact between the coffee and the threading, so not sure it should be fully food safe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there could be incidental contact it needs to be food safe. But fine ALUMINUM threads sounds pretty crappy.

Comment: try plumber's grease

Comment: Plumber’s grease if I’m not mistaken, is silicone based and used for o-rings and not metal. I’m think I saw somewhere that the lube for o-rings is not good enough for the threads

Comment: Lithium grease might be what you seek. Best to replace with what the manufacturer had there before. What did it look like? Is it essentially going inside a sealed gearbox?

Comment: Molykote 111 is NGLI 3-4. You probably want NGLI 1 or 2. Superlube makes a white PTFE-doped H1 food grade grease with NGLI rating 1. Real Moly dioxide greases are commonly speced for al threads, but I don't know about food grade, and they are horrible to work around.